# Настройка ToolTip для Combobox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Имеется коллекция объектов:

```
public class Param
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Эту коллекцию необходимо привязать к ComboBox так, чтобы в качестве элемента списка был Name, а в качестве всплываемой подсказки при наведении на каждый элемент был Description. Это легко делается:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox1"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,5"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=param.ListValue}"
              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=param.SubParamValue}">
              <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Description}"/>                        
                </DataTemplate>                    
              </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ComboBox>
```

Все бы ничего, но как сделать так, чтобы когда Description null или пустой, ToolTip вообще не отображался. Сейчас отображается пустой квадратик. Вариант ниже не помог. Заранее спасибо.

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox1"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,5"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=param.ListValue}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=param.SubParamValue}">                
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Name}">
                        <ListBoxItem.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip Background="LightYellow" Width="300" Opacity="0.8">
                                    <ToolTip.Style >
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">                                        
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Description}" Value="">
                                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ToolTip.Style>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock Name="tb1" Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ToolTip>
                            </ListBoxItem.ToolTip>
                        </ListBoxItem>                      
                    </DataTemplate>                    
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>                                
            </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас как-то сложно. Значение `null` должно убирать `ToolTip` и так, так что проблема только с пустой строкой. Проще всего просто отловить это через конвертер.

```
class NullIfEmptyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object p, CultureInfo ci) =>
        (string)value == string.Empty ? null : value;

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object p, CultureInfo ci) =>
        throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

(или, как подсказывает @Андрей в комментариях, `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)value) ? null : value`).

Ваш код получается таким:

```
<ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Name}"
             ToolTip="{Binding Description, Converter={StaticResource NullIfEmpty}}"/>
```

Не забудьте положить в ресурсы окна

```
<local:NullIfEmptyConverter x:Key="NullIfEmpty"/>
```

Comment: Блин, не успел :) Я бы написал так: `return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value as string) ? null : value;` от пары пробелов тоже толку мало

Comment: Спасибо!)) Помогло!

Comment: @Sergio: Пожалуйста!